# increasing numbers with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Is there a simple jQuery way to generate numbers using a `.class` containing different numbers more and more increasing after a few seconds?

**Example :**

*before :*

```
<p class="number_vp">56</p>

<p class="number_vp">2</p>
```

*after few seconds :*

```
<p class="number_vp">58</p>

<p class="number_vp">10</p>
```

Comment: What does "more randomly" mean?

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question buddy

Comment: no, there is a javascript way to generate random numbers though. `Math.random();` is what you're after. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range (thanks to @T.J.Crowder for the correction)

Comment: So you need a unique increasing random generator?

Comment: For example, I've 3 div that contains a <p> with different numbers, I would retrieve the value and add randomly to increase this value

Comment: `Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);` this give you random number between 1 and 10

Comment: If you mean: Adding a random number between 1-100 for all 'number_vp' elements, every second, then my answer has the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $p = $('.number_vp');

setInterval(function() {
    $p.html(function(_, num) {
        return +num + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    })
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eqseX/

Comment: +1 for the only answer (so far) with a numeric addition rather than a string concatenation, and for tidy use of a callback with `.html()`.

Comment: Nice use of .html(function(index,elm){ return returnHTML; }); didn't know that existed :)

Comment: @WillemMulder - You can use that callback system with lots of jQuery functions. It's a nice feature.

Comment: It certainly is! Although sometimes a more verbose version is easier to read, but that depends on the situation I guess :-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a random number between 1-100 for all 'number_vp' elements, every second:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".number_vp").each(function(index,elm) {
        var value = $(elm).html()*1;
        var newValue = value + Math.round(Math.random()*100);
        $(elm).html(newValue);
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Note that this adds a random number as a string concatentation, i.e., it adds more digits at the end...

Answer (score 0):

This code shows how to generate random numbers for your div items of class `number_vp`.

```
$('.number_vp').each(function(){
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*999);
    $(this).html(randomnumber);
});
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6JSXD/1/

---

This is a sample with a timer implemented, changing the values every 2 seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){
    changeNumbers();    
}, 2000);

function changeNumbers(){
    $('.number_vp').each(function(){
        var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*999);
        $(this).html(randomnumber);
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6JSXD/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(genRandom,10000);


function genRandom(){$(".number_vp").each(function(index,elm) {
    $(this).html(Math.round(Math.random()*100000));
    setTimeout(genRandom,10000);
});}
```